# Android BLE pairing with windows 10

Tags: android, windows, security, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing the folowing problems when trying to pair my Androids BluetoothGattServer and BluetoothLeAdvertiser with Windows 10. My BluetothGattCharacteristics are protected with 
PERMISSION_READ_ENCRYPTED_MITM / PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM.

1) When pairing windows, the I have to insert a constant pin "000000". That seams very unsecure compared to the passkey variant that is used pairing the same device with Bluetooth Classic.

2) Android 5 introduced rotating MAC addresses. Windows fails to reconnect to the paired device somehow.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Bluetooth Manager is showing "Driver Error" and the Device Manager reports "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)" on this device.

Comment: Windows 10 is known to have many problems with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: I also receive an error message in the Device Manager: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

Comment: Android has many bugs, too. So should I report this issue to Microsoft or Google?

Answer (score 0):

Just reported this Problem to Microsoft and Android.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/ble-pairing-with-android-and-windows-10-unsecure/df711d25-1c3e-4c7a-94f5-e5e6b8bc7a6f

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=250334

Lets see, if it might get solved...